# Difference between CACornerMask and UIRectCorner in swift

Tags: ios, swift

when i was trying to set corner radius in a view i saw i have two choices.

- CACornerMask
- UIRectCorner

what is difference between this 2 struct in swift:

`CACornerMask` and `UIRectCorner`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CACornerMask was added in iOS 11. It boils down to use cases.

We normally set corner radius to CALayer, so it's very easy to use CACornerMask.

```swift
let view = UIView()
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

As opposed to using UIRectCorner:

```swift
var cornerMask = UIRectCorner()
cornerMask.insert(.bottomLeft)
cornerMask.insert(.bottomRight)

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                        byRoundingCorners: cornerMask,
                        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath

let view = UIView()
view.layer.mask = mask
```

The second example becomes handy when you're already doing some UIBezierPath.

For most of simple use cases, you'd probably go with CACornerMask.